# Explain how MEF doesn't have hard dependency on assemblies

Tags: .net, mef

Reading through this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx I'm seeing a claim that MEF doesn't have a hard dependency on assemblies. I'm not exactly sure what this means because even though the contracts are strings, MEF still resolves by string, then by type. So both the host and extension assemblies need a reference to the contract assembly. Is this not a hard dependency?

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating
>   lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers
>   to discover and use extensions with no configuration required. It also
>   lets extension developers easily encapsulate code and avoid **fragile
>   hard dependencies**. MEF not only allows extensions to be reused within
>   applications, but across applications as well.
>
> ---
>
> Finally, the component developers must accept a **hard dependency** on
>   what assembly contains the interface they implement. This makes it
>   difficult for a component to be used in more than one application, and
>   can also create problems when you create a test framework for
>   components.
>
> ---
>
> Because the MEF model **requires no hard dependency** on a particular
>   application assembly, it allows extensions to be reused from
>   application to application. This also makes it easy to develop a test
>   harness, independent of the application, to test extension components.

Can someone explain this to me? Maybe I misunderstand what a hard dependency really is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that the only hard dependency (meaning that you explicitly reference the assembly) is on the assembly that defines your *interface*. The assemblies with specific *implementations* of that interface are not hard dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Typically most scenarios in MEF revolve around 1) a host, 2) a plugin and 3) a plugin contract., E.g., the host:

```
public class Host
{
    [ImportMany] IEnumerable<IPlugin> Plugins { get; set; }
}
```

A plugin:

```
public class SomePlugin : IPlugin
{
    // Operations
}
```

A plugin contract:

```
public interface IPlugin { }
```

Now, the host takes a hard (explicit) reference on the plugin contract. The plugin also takes a hard reference on the plugin contract. At composition time, MEF uses late binding to load the plugin assembly at runtime. Because of this, your host doesn't explicitly depend on the plugin assembly, its only dependency is the plugin contract assembly.